# Search second Workbook and Return Row Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA so excuse my ignorance as I have a question in relation to search and find.

Workbook 1 is where I have an invoicing template and Workbook 2 is where I have the billing information. So I am trying to set up Workbook 1 so that the user can come in and enter a unique billing ID from the billing workbook and then populate the values in the invoicing workbook.

So I need to workout how to search the billing workbook, return the row value and then use offset to return the values in the appropriate columns and then populate.

Any help would be appreciated. I am so limited that I can't attempt the code myself yet but even if someone was kind enough to put pseudo code it would be a big help.

Conor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to make it work in Workbook 2. Something like

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

would be the "Hello world" in this case. Once you have it working, you move it to Workbook 1, with this change:

```
Debug.Print Workbooks("Workbook 2").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
```

where Workbook2 is the name of that workbook
Everything after `ThisWorkbook` / `Workbooks("Workbook 2")` is specific for your case.